# How to insert Space after every Character of an existing String in Java?

Tags: java, string

I need to insert a space after every character of a string.

i.e.
`String name = "Joe";`

should become: `"J o e"`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Shorter would be using a regex:

```
System.out.println("Joe".replaceAll(".(?!$)", "$0 "));
```

Comment: This has the added advantage (compared to looping over the characters) that it doesn't break surrogate pairs.

Comment: Now you have two problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038186/are-there-particular-cases-where-native-text-manipulation-is-more-desirable-than

Comment: @Wouter: what do you mean by surrogate pairs?

Comment: @StuperUser: Pairs of characters used to represent characters outside the "Basic Multilingual Plane". See class description on http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Answer (score 27):

For **Android & Kotlin** users, if you want to add space after every **X** characters then use this

```
val stringWithSpaceAfterEvery4thChar = stringWith12Chars?.replace("....".toRegex(), "$0 ")
```

Here I added **4 dots in method** to add **space after every 4th character** in my whole string.
If you want space **after every 2 characters then add only 2 dots** in the method.

My variables:

```
stringWith12Chars = "123456789012"
```

and the output would be,

```
stringWithSpaceAfterEvery4thChar = "1234 5678 9012"
```

Comment: this is just perfect!

Comment: You gave proper logic.

Answer (score 10):

Something like:

```
String joe = "Joe";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (char c: joe.toCharArray()) {
   sb.append(c).append(" ");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
```

Comment: A slight optimization: `sb.setLength(sb.length() > 0 ? sb.length() - 1 : 0).toString();` i.e. trim the builder, not the result.

Answer (score 6):

This will space out all letters in each word and not between words

```
"Joe Black".replaceAll("\\B", " ") -> "J o e B l a c k"
```

This will put space for each character (including original spaces)

```
"Joe Black".replaceAll("\\B|\\b", " ") -> " J o e  B l a c k "
```

Answer (score 3):

Using kotlin

```
val textToBeDevided = "123456789" 
textToBeDevided
   .subSequence(1, textToBeDevided.length) 
   .chunked(3) // group every 3 chars
   .joinToString(" ") // merge them applying space
```

Comment: `.subSequence` call is redundant because `String` is already a `CharSequence`. Moreover, indexes in strings start from 0 so you've lost `"1"` in an output.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] stringArray = strOrig.toCharArray(); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int index=0; index < stringArray.length; index++) {
   sb.append(stringArray[index]);
   sb.append(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without regex

```
name.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i + " ").collect(Collectors.joining()).strip()
```

Don't like regex because compile method slow

Answer (score -1):

You can convert Joe to char[] by using String's toCharArray() then traverse char[] to grab the char into another char[] and as you add the char to the second char[], you add a space character '" "'. Set a if-else within the loop to detect the last character so that you wouldn't add a space character by accident behind the last character. Use a String to valueOf() the resulting char[] to turn it into a String object.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the final space:

```
String joe = "Joe"; 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
String sep = "";
for (char c: joe.toCharArray()) { 
    sb.append(sep).append(c);
    sep = " ";
} 

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```