# split the string as characters with whitespace in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert Space after every Character of an existing String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469984/how-to-insert-space-after-every-character-of-an-existing-string-in-java)

If I get string value from user then I want to display as separate characters.             for example:
            Enter the string: Orange
            Characters in the String: O r a n g e
Can you help any one for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
String text = "Orange";
String spaced = text.replaceAll("(.)", "$1 ");
System.out.println(spaced);
```

prints

```
O r a n g e
```

Comment: This homework smells like "loop"

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `String.toCharArray()`? Or just use the `length()` property and `charAt()` to get at each character individually.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

[`.toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.toCharArray()
```

then get the letters together with Spaces between.