# Insert space after every one or two characters in string

Tags: java, math, spacing, infix-notation

I need to write code to correct user input. The input is a mathematical expression in infix form. 
In order for my calculations to be correct, i need each operand spaced away from the operator.

Can you please help me write a method that will provide the following expected results.

Expected input: 13*21-5+33
Expected Output: 13 * 21 - 5 + 33

Research I have done: I could only find out how to add spaces between every character in the string and that will not work for calculating expressions with double digit values. Ie: 1 3 * 2 1 - 5 + 3 3. [How to insert Space after every Character of an existing String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469984/how-to-insert-space-after-every-character-of-an-existing-string-in-java)

Thanks

Comment: I can do this using simple string processing mechanism but that still requires me to at least 5 to 7 lines of code. Would be happy if someone posts a single line REGULAR EXPRESSION solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution normalizes the whitespace around each operator.

```
return expr.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\s*([-+/*])\\s*(?=\\d)", " $1 ");
```

Comment: i get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1 when using those lines.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the parens. See edit. Or, use $0 and no parens.

Comment: Thank you very much!
The original function i was trying to achieve was to put in the spaces if the user forgot to do it, what would be the best way to check if user put spaces or not? i only need to add the spaces if the user forgot to add them

Comment: @NullPointerException Use my second solution. This one inserts spaces only around operators that are missing it. EDIT: now it normalizes space, adding where needed, and also eliminating excess space.

Comment: I think i found a bug.
That solution eliminates the whitespace between the middle 2 operators
example outputs:

Enter infix expression 2*3-10/4
corrected infix :2 * 3-10 / 4

Enter infix expression 5+2*6-1
corrected infix :5 + 2*6 - 1

Enter infix expression 2 * 3-10 / 4
corrected infix :2 * 3-10 / 4

As you can see there are no spaces added around middle operator.

The rest works perfectly though.

Comment: this time i got java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2

Answer (score 2):

Look for digits using regex then surround them with spaces:

```
string.replaceAll("\\d+", " $0 ").trim(); // trim in case numbers are first/last
```

Comment: More elegant than the accepted answer for just numbers!