# Adding space between characters

Tags: java, string, space

I want to add space after every two chars in a string.

For example:

```
javastring
```

I want to turn this into:

```
ja va st ri ng
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469984/how-to-insert-space-after-every-character-of-an-existing-string-in-java

Comment: Loop the string variable with for or while instructions and after two characters print a space!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `'..'` to match each two characters and replace it with `"$0 "` to add the space:

```
s = s.replaceAll("..", "$0 ");
```

You may also want to trim the result to remove the extra space at the end.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/GuA9d).

Alternatively you can add a negative lookahead assertion to avoid adding the space at the end of the string:

```
s = s.replaceAll("..(?!$)", "$0 ");
```

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me from implementing the loop.

Answer (score 5):

`//Where n = no of character after you want space`

```
int n =2;
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP");
int idx = str.length() - n;
while (idx > 0){
   str.insert(idx, " ");
   idx = idx - n;
}
return str.toString();
```

Explanation, this code will add space from right to left:

```
str = "ABCDEFGH" int idx = total length - 2; //8-2=6
while (8>0)
{
    str.insert(idx, " "); //this will insert space at 6th position
    idx = idx - n; // then decrement 6-2=4 and run loop again
}
```

The final output will be

```
AB CD EF GH
```

Comment: this code will add space from right to left,
str = "ABCDEFGH"
int idx = total length - 2;//8-2=6
while (8>0){
   str.insert(idx, " ");//this will insert space at 6th position
   idx = idx - n;// then decrement 6-2=4 and run loop again
}
final output will be AB CD EF GH
Hope this explaination helps

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a generic solution for this...

```
public static String insertCharacterForEveryNDistance(int distance, String original, char c){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] charArrayOfOriginal = original.toCharArray();
    for(int ch = 0 ; ch < charArrayOfOriginal.length ; ch++){
        if(ch % distance == 0)
            sb.append(c).append(charArrayOfOriginal[ch]);
        else
            sb.append(charArrayOfOriginal[ch]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then call it like this...

```
String result = InsertSpaces.insertCharacterForEveryNDistance(2, "javastring", ' ');
System.out.println(result);
```