# Can Java String format be used here

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have a situation in which I need to display a string with some spaces in the UI. This is for better readability.

For example if my data is "1234567890", I want to display it as "123 456 7890". I was wondering if this can be done using Java's String format methods?

Comment: You can do it using StringBuilder - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469984/how-to-insert-space-after-every-character-of-an-existing-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd have to implement your own code. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the String API.

Comment: I wrote a utility method that would "return plainString.substring(0, 3) + " " + plainString.substring(3,6) + " " + plainString.substring(6,10);" its not pretty, but does the job i guess

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with replaceAll.

```
String test = "1112223333";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(.{3})(.{3})(.{4})", "$1 $2 $3"));
```

This uses the regular expression `(.{3})(.{3})(.{4})` the `.{x}` matches anything. the `{x}` is the number of times. I surround it in parenthesis `(.{3})` to capture the string that matches in $1, $2 and $3.

So $1 = "111", $2 = "222" and $3 = "3333"

Comment: what is this $1, $2 etc here?

Comment: I updated it. When you use parenthesis in a regex it captures the matching string and stores in in $1, $2, $3... for as mathing `()` you have in your regex. The whole string is also stored in $0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to format a phone number? You could use  `DecimalFormat`, define the message format and make a `String[]` with sub strings of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it with String.format() 
First you can split the string in an array to have

a[0]="123"

a[1]="456"

a[2]="7890"

then use the following

```
String.format("%1$3s %2$3s %3$3s",a );
```