# Solr returns incomplete search results

Tags: xml, solr

I am new to solr and have created a core which is searching through xml files. The search is working fine but it does not seem to be complete. When I search through my indexed files e.g. with "A" I get a result, when I use "*U*" I do not get a result even though there are records which would match the search string. Can you give me a hint where to check this issue? In my eyes the schema.xml and the data-config.xml seem properly defined.

Thanks for any advice in advance!

The fieldType is "text", I have attached the schema.xml here:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField"             positionIncrementGap="0" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField"     positionIncrementGap="0" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField"     positionIncrementGap="0" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="idauftrunters" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="patientname" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</schema>`
```

Sabine

Comment: what the fieldType used for the field? and what are the tokenozers and filters it has?

Comment: What does the "Analysis" page under Solr Admin show for the indexed content compared with the query string?

Comment: Can u tell which particular field you are searching on and how is that field analyzed in schema.xml

Comment: Are you expecting "U" to match within a term? Or match a specific term?

Comment: Yes, I expect it to match with all patientname containing a "*U*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone named Johnny U Dawg, your query as is should return results.

For someone named Johnny U. Dawg, you may want to add the [ClassicFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ClassicFilterFactory) or [LetterTokenizerFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LetterTokenizerFactory) and it should return results.

However, from what I understand, you want "Jes**u**s Gamez" to show up when you query with **U**

This is not straightforward in SOLR, the closest to this feature is EdgeNGramFilterFactory but it takes only the first letter as the token you expect.

One way to achieve this would be to write a [scriptTransformer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) (in your data config xml) and make the name to split on each letter, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469984/how-to-insert-space-after-every-character-of-an-existing-string-in-java), but in Javascript.
And store it in different field to that of your name field (say namespace) and add this namespace to your text field using copyField.