# Regex to extract Noun Phrases from a Part of Speech parse tree?

Tags: ruby, regex, nlp

I am trying to extract all three word noun phrases from a Stanford POS Parse Tree. Basically, anything that looks like:

```
(NP (TAG WORD) (TAG WORD) (TAG WORD))
```

Or:

```
(NP (TAG WORD) (TAG (TAG WORD) (TAG WORD)))
```

This is what a parse tree can look like:

```
(ROOT (SQ (VBZ Is) (NP (DT this)) (NP (DT an) (NN asthma) (NN attack)) (. ?)))
```

When I do this regex, it extracts the correct 3 word noun phrase:

```ruby
threeWordNounPhrases = full.scan(/\(NP \([^()]+ [^()]+\) \([^()]+ [^()]+\)\)/)
# => "(NP (DT an) (NN asthma) (NN attack))"
```

However, this does not work for something like:

```
(ROOT (SQ (NNP Should) (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VB watch) (NP (NP (NNP Game)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Thrones)))) ) (. ?)))
```

Which should return:

```
(NP (NP (NNP Game)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Thrones))))
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for free-form, unstructured content. Have you considered using an NLP gem, [such as `treat`](https://github.com/louismullie/treat/wiki/Quick-Tour)?

Comment: There also exist Ruby bindings for the Stanford Core NLP package: https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp

Comment: Not solvable reliably with regex. Parse (or otherwise get) the data as an actual tree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there particular cases where native text manipulation is more desirable than regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038186/are-there-particular-cases-where-native-text-manipulation-is-more-desirable-than)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708047/how-to-extract-the-noun-phrases-using-open-nlps-chunking-parser

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for three words, it is possible, but not pretty. For N words, the complexity of the regexp rises. Note that this is just for fun (and regexp/Oniguruma education); in reality, I'd suggest to go with what everyone else says: use a tree parsing library and manipulate the tree.

```
str = "(ROOT (SQ (NNP Should) (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VB watch) (NP (NP (NNP Game)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Thrones)))) ) (. ?)))"

re = /
  (?<tag>
    [A-Z]+
  ){0}

  (?<word>
    \( \g<tag> \s
    (?:
      [^()]+ |
      \g<word>
    )
    \)
  ){0}

  (?<word2>
    \g<word> \s \g<word> |
    \( \g<tag> \s \g<word2> \)
  ){0}

  (?<word3>
    \g<word> \s \g<word> \s \g<word> |
    \g<word2> \s \g<word> |
    \g<word> \s \g<word2> |
    \( \g<tag> \s \g<word3> \)
  ){0}
  \( NP \s \g<word3> \)
/x;

puts str[re]
# => (NP (NP (NNP Game)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Thrones))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to use regular expressions unless are able to consider all possible structures. What you did works for simple cases, but as you found, it fails with deeper, nested structures. I see two options:

1. From the point where you encounter `(NP` in the text, read in additional characters. Keep a running tally of parenthesis. Add to it when you see `(`, subtract when you see `)`. When you get to zero, you've reached the end of the `NP`.
2. Parse the tree using [rubytree](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubytree/versions/0.9.7). Extract all subtrees that are dominated by a node with label of `NP`. Convert the subtree back to string form by concatenating leaf nodes.